# Am I correctly adding multiple ports to a terraform resource spec?

Tags: terraform

I am relatively new to terraform and am following an example from the following link:

[link to example here][1]

Code Snippet from above link:

```
resource "kubernetes_service" "example" {
  metadata {
    name = "terraform-example"
  }
  spec {
    selector = {
      app = kubernetes_pod.example.metadata.0.labels.app
    }
    session_affinity = "ClientIP"
    port {
      port        = 8080
      target_port = 80
    }
```

If I need to specify multiple ports, would I achieve this as follows:

```
ports {
  port {
    name = "http-metrics"
    port = 8080
    target_port = "http-metrics"
  }
  port {
    name = "telemetry"
    port = 8081
    target_port = "telemetry"
  }      
}
```

I've been scouring the docs and googling without success. Any help is appreciated.

UPDATE:

I came across an example that writes it this way:

```
port {
  name        = "https"
  target_port = "http"
  port        = 443
}
port {
  name        = "http"
  target_port = "http"
  port        = 80
}
```

I am thinking this might be what I'm looking for, but would appreciate it if someone could weigh in.

Thanks again

Comment: How did it go? Still unclear on what you can do?

Comment: Thanks for confirming Marcin. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your updated version is the would you would specify multiple values of an [block-type attribute](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/attr-as-blocks.html) in terraform:

> Where multiple such objects are possible, **multiple blocks** of the same type can be present.

So in your case you just duplicate `port` block to create multiple values for `port` attribute.